# sudo rule with placeholder

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, ufw

i want to allow the use of `/usr/sbin/ufw` for a special user.

But only for a given command:

in my /etc/sudoers file i have now (for blocking **IPv4** addresses):

```
blockuser   ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ufw deny from [0-9\.]* to any
```

But when i try to execute the command i get an:

> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 27

error (which is the line i posted before).

So my question, is it possible to work with such a placeholders in sudo?

Comment: Seems: `/usr/sbin/ufw deny from [0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*` to any is working

Answer (score 1):

sudo is not using regular expression, it is using standard shell glob patterns.

So for blocking an IPv4 address you must use:

```
blockuser   ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/ufw deny from [0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]* to any
```

`\.` is not allowed